# gradle: can you apply plugin from command line

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I downloaded an open source gradle-built project and ran `gradle eclipse` but `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` was not in `build.gradle` so it failed. I edited the file and added the line then successfully ran `gradle eclipse`. I found this a bit clunky inasmuch as I'd prefer to be able to run `gradle eclipse` with some flag for instance so that I don't need to change the source at all. Is there an alternative to my action?

Comment: No, but you can use the Eclipse's plugin without needing the Gradle plugin activated

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem is to write custom gradle scripts in `~/.gradle/init.d/` such as this one:

```
allprojects {
    project.apply plugin: 'maven'
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

(this one is to ensure I can leverage mavenLocal repository in every gradle project, but you can do the same and apply eclipse plugin)

This scripts are executed in every gradle build (in alphabetical order, so using a convention similar to Linux init.d in naming can help, e.g. `00-eclipse.gradle`) and can enrich your build.

I favor this approach for things which would be user-specific and don't deserve to be in everyone's build script (eclipse/idea/mavenLocal fit that category, and I also apply [gradle-tools-plugin](https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-tools-plugin) for easier debugging through command line.

Note that like Ben mentioned, I usually recommend against using the eclipse/idea project generation plugins, but prefer the IDE gradle integration, but that's another story.

Comment: thanks for your answer, tis the closest I've got (don't really want called in every gradle build but oh well) and appreciate the advice about ide integration, I'll try it (again).